# Save errors - runtime '1004'

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, xlsm

I have an issue runtime error 1004 with the below code, could anyone clarify for me what could be driving this?

```
Sub Excel1()

   Dim rngLoopRange As Range
   Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
   Dim rngDealers As Worksheet

   Set wsSummary = Sheets("PL")

   For Each rngLoopRange In Worksheets("AUX").Range("A1:A38")
      wsSummary.Range("C12").Value = rngLoopRange.Value

    Application.Run "TM1REFRESH"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("C12").Value
    ws.Copy before = wb.Worksheets(1)


Next rngLoopRange

Set wsSummary = Nothing

    MsgBox "Complete!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

The above is now saving the file using the name I wanted, can you please advise now why it is giving me an

> error '424'

on the sheet copying over. with the code line `ws.Copy before = wb.Worksheets(1)`

```
Sub Excel1()

   Dim rngLoopRange As Range
   Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
   Dim rngDealers As Worksheet

   Set wsSummary = Sheets("PL")

   For Each rngLoopRange In Worksheets("AUX").Range("A1:A38")
      wsSummary.Range("C12").Value = rngLoopRange.Value

    Application.Run "TM1REFRESH"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wsSummary.Range("C12").Value
    ws.Copy before:=wb.Worksheets(1)
    wb.Close savechanges:=True


Next rngLoopRange

Set wsSummary = Nothing

    MsgBox "Complete!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line generates an error, and are you sure that `Range("C12").Value` is not empty?

Comment: Line C12 definitely has a value, but it is this line causing the problem, it is a formula though, would that be an issue?

Comment: You just added a new workbook, which will be active and C12 on its active sheet will be blank. Specify the sheet and workbook for the range too.

Comment: But I'm copying the data onto the new workbook, surely that populates the cell and then it looks at it that cell for reference to save?

Comment: No, you have a value C12 on Worksheets("AUX"), then you create a blank workbook and trying to take data of new book's C12, which is empty. This is how your code written.

Comment: Can you please advise how I correct this?

Comment: Think you need to add a reference to the sheet C12 is on - `wsSummary.Range("C12").Value` similarly you might want to consider if `ActiveWorkbook` needs to be more specific eg. `wb`